Flutter App Package Name Concatenation During Creation in Android Studio
Is there a way to prevent the project name from being concatenated with the package name when using the Flutter project creation UI in Android Studio?
I'm encountering an issue while creating new Flutter projects in Android Studio. When I specify a desired package name (e.g., com.example.my_app), the project name seems to be automatically appended to it, resulting in a package name like com.example.my_app.MyApp.
I understand that using the --org flag with flutter create in the command line can lead to this behavior. However, I'm creating projects through the Android Studio UI, where I don't have access to such flags.
Ideally, I'd like the package name to strictly match the value I enter during project creation.

Try below steps

Provide the project name
Make sure you don't append project name in Organization
Create a project that will only append once.


If you want to create using CLI try below command
flutter create --org com.demo test_project

